# String representation of a Symbol's prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

while i realize that Symbol's cannot be automatically/silently converted to Strings (see "Symbol type conversions" on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)):

```
s = Symbol('s');
typeof s;        // -> 'symbol'
s;               // -> 'Symbol (s)'
s.toString();    // -> 'Symbol (s)' using Symbol.prototype.toString()
String(s);       // -> 'Symbol (s)' using safe String(s) conversion
s +'';           // throws 'TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string' as expected
```

i am surprised/confused that trying to obtain a String representation of a ***Symbol's prototype*** throws an exception, whether using auto String conversion, explicitly calling `.toString` or using ["safer" String(sym) conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_conversion):

```
s = Symbol('s');
typeof s;                      // -> 'symbol'
p = Object.getPrototypeOf(s);  // -> Symbol {}
typeof p;                      // -> 'object'
p+'';          // -> TypeError: Method Symbol.prototype.valueOf called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
p.toString();  // -> TypeError: Method Symbol.prototype.toString called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
String(p);     // -> TypeError: Method Symbol.prototype.toString called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

since a Symbol's prototype seems to just be an Object, why would it not be possible to create a String representation of it?

i found something similar in this [post](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2012#discussion_r33101793) which references what seems to be the [ES6/2015 spec regarding converting Symbols to Strings](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring), but again i am confused as to why this would prevent a Symbol's prototype, which seems to be Object, from being converted to a String.

also, Node.js's [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) will output a String representation of a Symbol's prototype, though i have yet to figure out how/why from perusing the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js).

finally, it just seems like i am missing something basic about a Symbol's prototype: while it seems like it is a normal Object, maybe it is not?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Symbol.prototype` isn't a `Symbol` nor does it have an internal `[[SymbolData]]` slot.

> 19.4.3 Properties of the Symbol Prototype Object
>
> The Symbol prototype object is the intrinsic object %SymbolPrototype%. The Symbol prototype object is an ordinary object. **It is not a Symbol instance and does not have a [[SymbolData]] internal slot.**

Since it's not a Symbol and doesn't have a `[[SymbolData]]` internal slot it will fail on step 3b) of the `Symbol.prototype.toString` function.

> If s does not have a [[SymbolData]] internal slot, throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: But the toString method is called on the prototype (plain object), not on the Symbol instance

Comment: @JuanMendes, `toString` is a property of the prototype object, so it won't look in the prototype chain for `Object.prototype.toString`.